# odoo xml view calculation with "<=" and ">="

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-12

I have a odoo custom html report template (xml) and i want to calculate some data in javascript like the code below. How can i do this with operator "**<=**" and "**>=**"?

```js
for (let k in datas) {
  let _d = datas[k];
  if (_d.status >= 5) is_ok_arr.push(_d);
  else if (_d.status <= 2) is_pending_arr.push(_d);
  else not_ok_arr.push(_d);
}
```

With **&gte;** and **&lte;** replace for ">=" and "<=" will thow an error: lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Entity 'gte'/'lte' not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Create static/js/ folder in module. Create report.js in js folder. Write your javascript code in "report.js". Go xml file and import your js in template.

```
module_name
   --- static
       --- js
           --- report.js 
   --- models
   --- views

   #import js file in xml
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/module_name/static/js/report.js"/>
```

Comment: I have tried this before, but it doesn't work when print the report.